# Web Navigation not working after adding access rules

Tags: asp.net

Hey I ran into a problem after I added authentication roles and access rules. I added folders to my website so I could set restrictions on the web pages located in those folders.  I moved all the appropriate pages into the corresponding folders (admin pages into the admin folder, employee pages into the employee folder). When that was done I set up all my access rules and roles in the ASP.NET configuration.  Everything seemed to work fine but now my sitemap doesn’t work and I get the file not found error when trying to navigate my website.  This might be an easy fix but I am new to ASP.NET, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is go into your web.sitemap file and add the folder names that  you put the corresponding files in.

Ex. you put your admin pages in your admin folder so in your sitemap file it should look like this:
~\Admin\AdminPage.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow that was a brain fart on my half. Thanks I forgot that I would have to change the navigation in the sitemap after I moved the webpages into a folder.